# PREDICT set for a LL(1) parser help me fix it

Tags: parsing, grammar, compiler-construction

I am trying to build a compiler for a college projec. Currently I am having problems to create a part of my predict set for the LL(1) grammar. This is the part of my grammar that I am having problems with:

```
<DECLS>  ::- id <DECL> <N_DECL>
<N_DECL> ::- op_, <DECLS> | null
<DECL>   ::- <SOMETHING_MORE>
```

The first sets for this part of the grammar are:

```
<DECLS>  = id
<N_DECL> = op_ , null
```

The follow sets for this part of the grammar are:

```
<DECLS>  = op_; , op_,
<N_DECL> = op_; , op_,
```

The predict set for this part of the grammar is (see as a matrix):

```
                   id                      op_,
<DECLS>    id <DECL> <N_DECL> 
<N_DECL>                               op_, <DECLS> / null      <--- here
```

As you can see the entry for `N_DECL` and `op_` has two entries. As far as I know, a grammar is wrong if the predict set has two or more entries in the same box. So I was wondering if someone can help me changing my grammar to solve this problem.

Comment: If I understand your notation correctly, wouldn't you mean that the `FIRST` set for `<N_DECL>` is `op_, , null`, rather than `op_ , null`?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your notation correctly, then

- *FIRST(*`<N_DECL>`*) = {* `op_,` *,* `null` *}*
- *FOLLOW(*`<N_DECL>`*) = {* `op_;` *,* `op_,` *}*

I don't see where `op_,` in `<N_DECL>`'s FOLLOW set comes from (perhaps it's coming from a different part of your grammar), but if it's really there, your grammar would be ambiguous due to a **FIRST/FOLLOW conflict**. These occur whenever the FIRST set of a non-terminal contain `null` (i.e. the non-terminal can produce the empty string), and the FIRST and FOLLOW set of that non-terminal overlap. In this case, they both contain `op_,`, which causes problems as you have noticed.

From the fact that you list `op_,` in `<DECLS>`'s FOLLOW set, I deduce that the actual ambiguity arises from a part of the grammar that you didn't include in your question. If you're parsing a `<DECLS>` with a lookahead of one token, encountering a comma may mean that you have another `op_, id <DECL> <N_DECL>` phrase, or that that comma belongs to a structure where the comma is "outside" the `<DECLS>`.

It might be that your language is LL(1), but without knowing *why* `<DECLS>` can be followed by `op_,`, I wouldn't know how to resolve this conflict. However, if it turns out that your language isn't LL(1) as it is tokenised now, you should consider tricking the tokeniser to do the lookahead for you:

- Use substitution to arrive at `<N_DECL> ::- op_, id <DECL> <N_DECL> | null`.
- Let the lexer parse `op_, id` as its own token `comma_id`.
- Correct the production: `<N_DECL> ::- comma_id <DECL> <N_DECL> | null`.